# Opening a file using a variable name

Tags: c++

If I change myfile("input.txt") to myfile(file_name)...where file_name is passed to the function it does not work but gives the error no matching function call..which I'm guessing b.c. I'm not suppose to be passing a string to the constructor...if not this way..how?

```
void file_to_string(string file_name)
{
   string line;  
   ifstream myfile("input.txt");
   if(myfile.is_open())
   {
      while(myfile.good())
      {
         getline(myfile,line);
         cout << line;
      }
      myfile.close();
  }
  else
  {
      cout << "File : " << file_name << " : did not open" ;
  }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    file_to_string(argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: See my answer for some possible insights into this strange matter. I share your opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `c_str()` member of the `std::string` class:

```
ifstream myfile(file_name.c_str());
```

It returns a null-terminated `const char *` representation of the string in question, which is exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 6):

`file_name` is a `std::string`, but the `ifstream` constructor wants a plain C-style string (pointer to `char`). So just use:

```
iftsream myfile(file_name.c_str());
```

This is a rather unclean part of the library and IMHO due to the fact that the stream library is older than the STL (from which `std::string` was taken). So the stream library doesn't really know about `std::string`. This is also the reason for `std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)` being a seperate function (and part of `<string>` rather than `<istream>` or something the like), I think.

One can see this as a clean separation of components, but I think `std::string` should be the standard for strings in C++ and therefore also be used by the stream library (at least its interface). And as the standard library is always to be seen as a whole, this is just a poor example of components working together cleanly. Maybe a future standard will address this.

**EDIT:** According to Benjamin's comment (and my reading through the standard draft) C++11 seems to indeed address this issue and you can now use a `std::string` as filename. But I guess you're not yet using C++11.

Comment: C++11 does in fact address this, and some library distros implement it now.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oh nice, I didn't know that. I'm not that fit in C++11 yet. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of std::ifstream takes the file name as const char*. You can convert a std::string to a const char* by using the c_str() member function.

```
 void file_to_string(string file_name)
  {
  string line;  
  ifstream myfile(file_name.c_str()); //convert string to const char*
  if(myfile.is_open())
    {
    while(myfile.good())
      {
      getline(myfile,line);
      cout << line;
      }
    myfile.close();
    }
  else
    {
    cout << "File : " << file_name << " : did not open" ;
    }
  }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  file_to_string(argv[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ifstream takes a const char* as parameter, so you cannot pass a std::string to it.
Maybe you could try:

```
 std::string fileName;
 ... // fill fileName
 ifstream myfile( fileName.c_str() );
```